# Autonomy teamsite item status

Tags: teamsite, autonomy

I am wondering if you can assign a status to .page or dcr files in teamsite such as new, review, revise, publish and archive so that this would display in the cms system so each item is clearly identified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible to assign it in the CMS interface. When I try to control the file status, I do it with workflows. For instance, developing a review workflow that creates a dcr, assigns the review to a review user, then finally creates the edition and deploys it to the Livesite server.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You could add your own extended attribute to keep the status of the file, but it won't be seen in the main teamsite interface.  You'll have to click on the Tag link in order to see what the status of the file is, then do with the file as you wish.  But if you have some backend to check the file's extended attribute, you would know the status.  You can use either the command line tool iwextattr or use the cssdk api to get the extended attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using metatags. You can add metatags to files using file->tag. Please configure \interwoven\TeamSite\local\config\datacapture.cfg to add fields to the meta tag ui. You can also add the statuses you mentioned as categories in taxonomy and add a field to select taxonomy categories as meta tag values. Use below code for that. Once we add meta tags. You can find those files via LSCS query filter the documents.

```
<item name="ContentCategories"> 
      <label>Related Categories</label>  
      <description>Select other locations on the site where you would like this content to be visible.</description>  
      <textarea required="f" rows="8" cols="70" wrap="virtual" maxlength="250" readonly="t"> 
        <cgi-callout url="/iw-cc/livesite/taxonomyexplorer/Taxonomy.do?categoryTypeId=Content Categories&amp;method=loadTaxonomyExplorer&amp;selectMode=multiple" label="Select Related Categories..." window-features="width=495,height=375,resizable=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no"/> 
      </textarea> 
    </item>
```